# Angular get video duration and store in external variable

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get video duration, I can get it in the console but I can't reach it and store in DB or even alert it. If I tried to console it as `console.log(file.duration)` I get `undefined`. This is the code:

```js
setFileInfo(file) {
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.preload = 'metadata';
  video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
    var duration = video.duration;
    file.duration = duration;
  }

  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need just to patch result of the video duration inside setFileInfo function

```
 setFileInfo(file) {
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.preload = 'metadata';
  video.onloadedmetadata = ()=> {
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
  var duration = video.duration;
  file.duration = duration;
  this.form.patchValue({duration:file.duration});
    }
   video.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
 }
```